# Convert to two decimal values after point

Tags: java, android, android-studio, floating-point

I want to convert 283.8 to 283.80

Used below code but didn't work...plz help

```
holder.walletBal.setText("$ " +String.format( "%.2f",283.8));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**`DecimalFormat`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat)

Try this

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
Log.e("ANSWER",df.format(Double.parseDouble("283.8")));
```

**OUTPUT**

```
11-26 11:02:59.021 23883-23883/neel.com.rxjavademo E/ANSWER: 283.80
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try with below code.

```
val value = 283.8f
String.format("%.02f", value))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a good way to put below method in your Utils class. It is working fine.

```
public static String roundToTwoDigit(Double paramDouble) {

    if (!CommonUtils.isTextAvailable(String.valueOf(paramDouble))) return "";

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

    String strValue=df.format(paramDouble);

    // String doubleValue= String.valueOf(Double.valueOf(strValue));

    Log.e("ad","roundToTwoDigit ="+strValue);

    return strValue;
}
```